# How to select ONLY posts from friends and viewing user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logic

I'm making a social plugin for my website, and I have a friends table that holds all accepted friend requests, and I need to display all posts from the users friend AND the users posts in order of the date, so I've tried this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `social_posts`.*, `social_friends`.*, `users`.* 
FROM `social_posts` 
JOIN `social_friends` 
ON `fUID` = '1' AND `friend` = `pUID` OR `pUID` = '1' 
JOIN `users` 
ON `friend` = `uid`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `social_friends` (
  `fID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fUID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `social_posts` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pUID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

fUID is the users (viewing) user ID, and friend is the users friend, and pUID is the user ID of the user who made the post.

But this shows two of each post, even with `SELECT DISTINCT`, and I'm out of ideas on how to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Can you give as more info (the fields) of the tables?
What is fUID and pUID

2 - Try and change

```
ON `fUID` = '1' AND `friend` = `pUID` OR `pUID` = '1'
```

to `ON friend = pUID` and put `fUID = 1 OR pUID = 1` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I explained the column names more in depth, and where would I put a WHERE clause when there are JOIN clause's

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `social_posts`.*, `social_friends`.*, `users`.* 
FROM `social_posts` 
JOIN `social_friends` 
ON `friend` = `pUID` 
JOIN `users` 
ON `friend` = `uid`
WHERE `fUID` = '1'  OR `pUID` = '1'
ORDER BY `date` DESC